# How to get Selected row ID in controller by clicking the Delete button on view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I bind my list to the table like below image. I am unable to get the #ID in controller when the delete button pressed. Please guide me someone how to get the selected #ID in the controller when delete button pressed?

[image]

Here is my controller code.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddOrUpdateProducts(ProjectViewModel model = null, string Command = null)
    {
        if (Command == "Delete")
        {
        //Delete Item from list by #ID from 
        }
        if (Command == "Submit")
        {
            //Save Items list
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden field in your view

```
<input type="hidden" id="forid" name=""forid"/>
```

In view ,as far as I can see every element is inside td.You can use jquery click function to change value of hidden field like below

```
$('.delete').click(function(){

    var id=$(this).parents('tr').children(':first').text();// I am supposing that id is placed in first td of row then set this value to hidden field
     $('#forid') .val(id);

})
```

Then in controller you can get this value using `Request["forid"]`

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddOrUpdateProducts(ProjectViewModel model = null, string Command = null)
    {
        if (Command == "Delete")
        {
         int id=int.Parse(Request["forid"].ToString());
        //Delete Item from list by #ID from 
        }
        if (Command == "Submit")
        {
            //Save Items list
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```